# Get IP with just knowing MAC address

Tags: windows, batch-file, networking

I'm trying to write a batch file, that gives me an IP back, but I just know the MAC address

```
arp -a
```

wont work for me, because I never pinged that IP before. I want to search for it in the network with literally just knowing the MAC address.

> Information: The IP is static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "skip=3 delims=\" %%A in ('net view ^| findstr /v /C:"The command completed successfully"') do Echo %%A >> "%userprofile%\desktop\computerlist.txt"
```

Lists turned on computers.

```
 wmic /node:@computerlist.txt nicconfig where macaddress='whatever:whatever:etc' get ipaddress /format:htable
```

To get IP for a specified MACAddress

```
 wmic /node:@computerlist.txt nicconfig get ipaddress /format:htable
```

to get the IPAddress for all MACAddresses on a computer.

Comment: I don't know if this is the final solution. I can tell this hopefully tomorrow. But for now I have a question: The first command loops through everything and saves it in a .txt document. With that done I could just loop through the arp table, or better not? And why?

Comment: Doesn't work -- first command gives -- `System error 6118 has occurred.` `The list of servers for this workgroup is not currently available` -- meanwhile my device shows up in `arp -a`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming, your subnet is 192.168.1.xxx

```
@echo off
REM clear arp cache (optional):
arp -d
REM ask everybody on the subnet for a response:
for /l %%a in (1,1,255) do start /b ping -n 2 -w 500 192.168.1.%%a >nul
REM wait for the processes to finish:
timeout 2 >nul
REM show the responses (with IP and MAC):
arp -a
```

When you found the IP, you can try to resolve the computer name with:

```
ping -a -n 1 192.168.1.xxx
```

**Edit** found a way to speed it up.

Comment: ... and what if you're not on a 24-bit subnet?

Answer (score 2):

Edit : just realized you where on Windows. Sadly, there is no native way to ping on braodcast addresses with Windows, but you can use the trick from [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/417045/how-to-enable-response-to-broadcast-ping-on-windows#answer-596830) : `FOR /L %i in (1,1,255) do @ping -n 1 192.168.1.%i | find "Reply"`. It seems super slow though.

Previous answer is below.

---

As far as I know, you have to fill in your ARP cache to do what you want.
[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86165/can-one-ping-a-nic-by-mac#answer-86193) is what you need.

As the post says, you can :

- ping all hosts of your LAN by pinging your broadcast address  (`ping -b -c1 192.168.1.255`, replace the IP by your actual broadcast address)
- fping your whole network (`fping -a -g 192.168.1.0/24`, replace with your actual netmask)
- nmap the network (`nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24`)
- nbtscan (windows hosts only, `nbtscan 192.168.1.0/24`)

And then look up in your ARP cache.

Answer (score 0):

I remember that ***sachadee*** posted this code **ScanIP-MAC.bat**

```
@echo off
Title Scan for IP and MAC Adress on LAN
mode con cols=60 lines=20
Color A
set ip=192.168.1.1
set debut=1
set fin=10
if exist ping.txt  (del  ping.txt)
if exist ping2.txt (del  ping2.txt)
if exist ping3.txt (del  ping3.txt)
if exist ping4.txt (del  ping4.txt)
for /L %%i in (%debut%,1,%fin%) do (echo Recherche de la machine : %ip:~0,9%.%%i
    for /f "tokens=5 delims= " %%f in ('ping -4 -n 1 %ip:~0,9%.%%i ^|find /i "32"') do (echo %%f >> ping.txt
    )
        for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%k in ('Type ping.txt ^|findstr /i "19"') do echo %%k > ping2.txt
            for /f %%l in (ping2.txt) do (arp -a %%l >> ping3.txt
        )
            )
Cmd /U /C Type ping3.txt > ping4.txt
Del ping.txt
Del ping2.txt
Del ping3.txt
Start ping4.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not a batch user so i dont know the commands but i know the way to do this is sending  broadcast ping request to ur network and check for the mac address from the reply's using wireshark.